How to align the rotation of the origin with the rotation of object itself (Align/Sync edit mode origin rotation with object mode rotation)
i would like to realise a simple thing but im afraid the answer isnt that easy. i'm googeling for days now and cant seem to find an answer. So i created an object with geometry nodes, curve to mesh follow by "seperate by loose part" now every object has the Origin rotation of the initial object/mesh before the seperation.
Example BlendFile:

As you can see in the picture the Origin rotation does not match with the actual rotation as can be observed in the 3D viewport.
I'm trying to align the rotation of the individual Origins with the individual objects.
so it looks like this without editing each individual object in edit mode: See picture below

I tried a custom Transform orientation and apply this to all object but then all the rotations get the rotation of the object/face of the selected object.
How would one accomplish this ?
Exact steps for others to reproduce the error
1. Shift + A Add > Curve > Path
2. Select NurbsPath object just created and go to Geometry Nodes tab.
3. Hit + button to add a new geometry node setup
4. Create basic geometry nodes setup to instance a cube along a Nurbspath Group input > Curve to points > Instance on Points > Realize Instance > Group Output Cube > Instance on Points
5. Select NurbsPath in 3D viewport in Object mode and go to Object > Convert > Mesh
6. Go to Edit mode and Hit A to select all and go to: Mesh > Separate > By Loose Parts
7. Go Back to edit mode an go to Options --> enable "Origins" to view the rotation of the origin.

My question: how do i "Bulk, read: all object at once" align the individual origin rotation with the ortation viewed in 3d viewport

it would be helpful if you provide a blend file with your GN node tree (because you didn't show us any technical details) and so we don't waste time recreating it and we can practically test, whether our solution proposal works.

It amazes me there isn't an 'Instance on Curve' operator/relation.. maybe I'm missing something. The quickest route I've found is : 1: Convert the curve to mesh, (resampling in GN if necessary) 2: In Relations, set the mesh up to instance on vertices, and parent the cube to the mesh. 3:  Ctrl-A Make instances real. If that's acceptable , will post.

EDIT: added example .BlendFile

@Robin Betts: This doesnt work, rotation is still off.
